# Display Sum of a calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I have one calculated column and I want to display the sum of all its values but I know that's impossible in a OOTB way. How can I copy all the values to a new column (type number)? 
Do I need to use JavaScript?

ps: I'm using SharePoint on-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't paste the whole page with detailed instructions

But you can get this:

[image]

By wacking some HTML & JavaScript in a Calculated Column.

Not suggested for large volume lists, but fine for Views that fit in your display.

Takes 9 steps and some 15 minutes (or 2 if you just copy/paste the last step)

See: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/Sum

## CSR version:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function sumColumn(columnName){
    var rows=ctx.ListData.Row; // global ctx!!
    var sum=rows.reduce(function(sums,item){  // loop over all Array items
        var value=item[columnName];
        return sums + (value ? Number(value) : 0); // calculate sums, does not take care of strings!
    },0); // sums starts at 0
    var id="Sum"+columnName; // unique id so multiple columns can be summed
    var sumDIV=document.getElementById(id);
    if(!sumDIV){ // if no Sum div exist
      sumDIV=document.createElement('DIV');
      sumDIV.id=id;
      // find column
      var header=document.querySelector("[id*='thead-WPQ1'] div[name='"+columnName+"']");
      header.appendChild(sumDIV);
    }
    sumDIV.innerHTML=String.format("<B>Sum: {0}</B>",sum);
  }

  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      Templates: {},
      OnPostRender: function(ctx) { 
        sumColumn('MonthSpan');   // USE INTERNAL FIELD NAME!
      },
    });
  }
  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/sumcalculated.js"), init);
  init();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to see it there's a quick and easy way with no prog languages.

Because I see the objective is to "display" the sum of all calculated volume.

1) Go to [modify view], expand [totals]. Select "sum" for the column that you want the sum to be displayed.

The sum will be on display in your main list/library.

2) If you need a breakdown of "sum" into 'sub-sum's based on other columns, you can do so too.
Go to [modify view], expand [group by]. Select the column(s) you want to create subgroup with. 
The *total* sum will be on display in your main list/library; and a 'sub-sum' will be displayed for each of the groups.